# Can't get a list of globally installed Node.js modules in Node v5.X

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have multiple Node.js versions on my computer, and i'm using [n](https://github.com/tj/n) to switch back and forth between versions.
When i'm using **version 4.0** which is the first version that I've installed i can use the following command to list all the globally installed node modules :

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

Whereas when using **5.x versions** like (*5.0.0 or 5.2.0*) i get a an empty string, meaning that there is no global modules.

I've also tried to get the **path** to global modules under version *4.0.0* and higher using the following command :

```
npm root -g
```

and surprisingly it was the same path.

What i can't grasp here is  how can it come that they share the same path and i'm getting different results in different versions.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This a bug in `npm` version *3.5.3* which comes with `node` *5.x*. You can read more about it here: [npm can't list global packages](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10708)

You can view all the installed packages by executing `ls` on the root directory.

Comment: Yes we can use ``ls`` but i need to access that path programmatically for other reasons.